# 'Are there any free phone plans in the Toronto area?': closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92617/13759: why was this closed?

It is analogous to [Prepaid SIM card in France with Free mobile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46025/13759).

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand how the previous question is analogous at all. That question was asking why a FreedomPop customer was assessed a roaming charge when traveling in Barcelona. Your question asks whether "any" service like FreedomPop is available in Toronto.

Our goal is to build a library of *definitive* questions and answers. While it's an interesting question on some level, it isn't a ["good" question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It doesn't show any initial research. It doesn't show any connection to travel. It asks for the existence or non-existence of a product, which is very difficult to prove in the negative except by citing web searches, which are the kind of initial research you should have demonstrated in the first place. It's unclear how it is a real-life problem as opposed to a theoretical exercise. What is a good answer to such a question supposed to look like?

You are an experienced StackExchange user with many well-regarded posts. I neither downvoted nor closevoted, but I would have expected a much stronger question.